# List members of in computer account on AD

Tags: vbscript

I am looking into finding a `vbscript` that I can get all the Groups inside "members of" a computer account onto a text file. For "members of" users account to be copied out to a text, I use a command of net user test `/domain` `c:\temp\testaccount.txt` & I wll get all the members of or `Local/Global` Group Memberships details within seconds. Is there a command to run or is a script needed?

Melvin

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script i use for that but this will never run as fast as a console command like yours, if that is a problem you can execute the command from a script with a run command.
You need to know the LDAP path for your domain. Because of the echoing you better run this with cscript.exe.

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8, CreateIfNeeded = true
Dim fso, filename, objConnection, objCommand, oShell, sResult, objRecordSet, oFile_out
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
filename = "\\server\share\out.txt"
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;"
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCommand.CommandText = "<LDAP://domain/OU=Workstations,OU=Computers,...>;;name;subtree"
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
sResult = oShell.Popup("Generating list..", 2, "Have some patience please, the list is generated")
on error resume next
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
Call CheckForError
set oFile_out = fso.OpenTextFile (filename, ForWriting, CreateIfNeeded)
Call CheckForError
While Not objRecordset.EOF
  oFile_out.writeline objRecordset.Fields("name")
  Wscript.Echo objRecordset.Fields("name")
  objRecordset.MoveNext
Wend
'--- ---'
Sub CheckForError
  if err.number <> 0 Then
    msgbox("39: "&err.description)
    err.clear
  end if
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Peter. I've tried the script that you've placed here. With only 1 modification but it failed at line 2. with error "name redefined", Code "800A0411".

Comment: Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8, CreateIfNeeded = true
Dim sResult, oShell, fso, filename, objConnection, objCommand, oShell, sResult, objRecordSet, oFile_out
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
filename = "D:\script\out.txt"
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Comment: yes, added some missing dim's afterward, 2 were allready there, should be ok now. is part of a working script but had to cut and paste a bit and obfuscate of course